# Adaptar target iframe a blank si es movil

Tags: iframe

Estoy desarollando una pagina con un iframe que al hacer click en un contenido se visualiza en este.

¿Hay una manera que cuando sea visualizada desde celular el codigo :

```
<a href="{{post.post_link}}" target="iframe1">
```

poder adaptarlo a que se abra una ventana nueva target="_blank"?

muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor añade código o lo que lleves echo. Así sin nada de apoyo es practicamente imposible poder echarte un cable. Saludos y suerte!

Comment: Ahi lo agregue! Gracias!

Comment: Probaste agregar al link la etiqueta `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Hola! @FranIslas el link esta como <a href="{{post.post_link}}" target=""iframe1">  para que en la vista standard web se visualicen al lado de la columna donde aparece el contenido.